# How to make a "clickable" row in Android and highlight the row and texts in TextView

Tags: java, android

I've created a class called `ClickableRow` which highlights the row and changes the text color of all the `TextViews` inside of it, then returns the row to its initial settings after the user stops clicking or scrolls too far, but I feel like android probably already has a built in function for this.

The main thing that I want to accomplish is to change all the `TextViews` in the row so that they are white when a click happens, and return to their previous color after a click or a scroll happens. I am sort-of accomplishing this, but for now I just have it turning the TextViews text to black afterwards. This isn't always the correct color, so is there a way to highlight text on a click and put it back to its default after?

Thanks.

Comment: Just store the original color before you change it to white and then change it back to the stored value instead of black.

Comment: what is this ClickableRow? Is it a ViewGroup? (LinearLayout/FrameLayout...) or just a class that controls textviews?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a handy property of all `Views` in android called the `Tag` (as you might know).

It means you can store whatever you want as data in a particular View.

So in your case, you will store the textview desired color in its TAG, so you can trivially know its state:

```
    void setTextViewColor(TextView textView, int color) {
          textView.setTag((Integer)color);
          textView.setColor(color);
    }

    void restoreTextViewToItsDefaultColor(TextView textView) {
        Integer myColor=(Integer)textView.getTag();
        textView.setColor(myColor);
    }
```

So given a TextView:

```
 TextView myTextView=new TextView(context);

 setTextViewColor (Color.RED); // sets to red AND stores red in the tag
```

later on, you manually change to your row color:

```
myTextView.setColor(Color.BLUE);
```

then to revert to the original you do

```
 restoreTextViewToItsDefaultColor(myTextView);
```

If you manually change

hope it helps !